# Old fortran code and getting an OPEN statement error using GNU

Tags: fortran, gnu, gfortran

I'm trying to compile a very old code but I get this error while compiling the code

```
   Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)
```

The code:

```
      WRITE(LUTTO,'('' TYPE NAME OF FILE CONTAINING INPUT   : '',$)')
C      READ (LUTTI,'(Q,A)') NCHAR,FILNAM
      READ (LUTTI,'(A)') FILNAM
      NCHAR = len_trim(FILNAM)
C                                             ----- OPEN DATA FILE -----
      print *, "NCHAR"
      OPEN( UNIT           = LUINP, NAME  = FILNAM(1:NCHAR),
     $      STATUS         = 'OLD', RECL  =             80 ,
     $      CARRIAGECONTROL= 'LIST', ERR   =           9900 )
```

Comment: We can't help you unless one has a minimal working example.

Comment: from gfortran docs "Some Fortran compilers, including g77, let the user declare OPEN( ... NAME=). This is invalid standard Fortran syntax and is not supported by gfortran. OPEN( ... NAME=) should be replaced with OPEN( ... FILE=). "

Comment: `CARRIAGECONTROL` is also not standard.  I believe "LIST" requests no carriage control, which is what modern compilers do by default so just get rid of it.   Kind of sad your compiler doesn't give a more informative error message.   FWIW carrige control would put an extra blank space at the start of every line, which you may or may not even notice.

Answer (score 2):

name=... in the open statement is invalid

try file=... instead

Comment: I just saw that in the GNU documentation.  I think it now has something to do with the carriagecontrol or the err

Comment: you should delete "carriagecontrol=list" as well as "recl=80" which are not necessary. About err=9900, you just have to check the existence of the label 9900 somewhere in your procedure...